# Name error not defined python

Tags: python

I am writing some code however I get this error I don't know whats wrong with it I'm defining the function as well any help is very much appreciated Thanks I get the roor that:

> Name Error headers_list is not defined

Comment: "This error"...what error? You need to include that in your question.

Comment: You're calling the `headers()` function with the opposite paremeters (`b,a` rather than `a,b`).  Also, note that this normally means you don't have a variable called `headers_list`.

Comment: Could you show us the code that causes the error? Otherwise we can only guess what's wrong..